# How can I retrieve the newest record in each group in a DBIx::Class resultset search?

Tags: sql, perl, search, group-by, dbix-class

I'm using **group_by** in a [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/~elliott/DBIx-Class-0.06002/lib/DBIx/Class.pm) resultset search. The result returned for each group is always the row in the group with the lowest id (i.e the oldest row in the group). I'm looking for a way to get the row with the highest id (i.e. the newest row in the group) instead.

The problem is fundamentally the same as this:
[Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)
...except that I'm using DBIx::Class not raw SQL.

To put the question in context:

I have a table of music reviews

```
review
------
id
artist_id
album_id
pub_date
...other_columns...
```

There can be multiple reviews for any given artist_id/album_id. 
I want the most recent reviews, in descending date order, with no more than one review per artist_id/album_id.

I tried to do this using:

```
$schema->resultset('Review')->search(
  undef,
  {
    group_by => [ qw/ artist_id album_id / ],
    order_by => { -desc => 'pub_date' },
  }
);
```

This nearly works, but returns the oldest review in each group instead of the newest.
How can I get the newest?

Comment: Maybe `-desc` => `-asc`?

Comment: J0HN - the order_by is applied after the grouping has been done so it won't affect which result is returned for each group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work you are relying on broken database behaviour. You should not be able to select columns from a table when you use **group by** unless they use an aggregate function (min, max etc.) or are specified in the group by clause.

In MySQL, [even the manual admits this is wrong](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) - though it supports it.

What I think you need to do is get the latest dates of the reviews, with max(pub_date):

```
my $dates = $schema->resultset('Review')->search({},
  {
    select   => ['artist_id', 'album_id', {max => 'pub_date'}],
    as       => [ qw(artist_id album_id recent_pub_date) ],
    group_by => [ qw(artist_id album_id) ],
  }
);
```

Then loop through to get the review:

```
while (my $review_date = $dates->next) {
    my $review = $schema->resultset('Review')->search({
        artist_id => $review_date->artist_id,
        album_id  => $review_date->album_id,
        pub_date  => $review_date->get_column('recent_pub_date'),
    })->first;
}
```

Yep - it's more queries but it makes sense - what if two reviews are on the same date - how should the DB know which one to return in the select statement?